# How to get top-level folders in an S3 bucket using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an S3 bucket with a few top level folders, and hundreds of files in each of these folders. How do I get the names of these top level folders?

I have tried the following:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-west-2', endpoint_url='https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com')
bucket = s3.Bucket('XXX')

for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='', Delimiter='/'):
    print obj.key
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I have thought about using regex to filter all the folder names, but this doesn't seem time efficient.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that is not possible with boto3 without listing the whole bucket.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')
result = paginator.paginate(Bucket='my-bucket', Delimiter='/')
for prefix in result.search('CommonPrefixes'):
    print(prefix.get('Prefix'))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, you might want to catch an exception in case such a bucket doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Amazon Athena in order to analyse/query S3 buckets.

https://aws.amazon.com/athena/

Answer (score -1):

> The Amazon S3 data model is a flat structure: you create a bucket, and the bucket stores objects. There is no hierarchy of subbuckets or subfolders; however, you can infer logical hierarchy using key name prefixes and delimiters as the Amazon S3 console does ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-keys))

In other words, there's no way around iterating all of the keys in the bucket and extracting whatever structure that you want to see (depending on your needs, a dict-of-dicts may be a good approach for you).

Comment: Well, but when you actually check the new S3 web UI, they list stuff like regular folders. So I think AWS is trying to provide that function now.